# php move_uploaded_file not working?

Tags: php

I'm attempting to upload a file with plupload and everything is working until `move_uploaded_file`.

The file isn't being uploaded. What is being returned is `00`

```
if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES["file"]["error"]) {
      die('{"OK": 0}');
    }

    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "http://example.co.uk/images/products/$fileName")) {
        die('{"OK": 1}');
    } else {
       die('{"OK": 00}');
    }
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: you're moving to a url. NOT possible. m_u_f() works at the local file system level and has no idea what to do with urls. and besides, even if you COULD move to a url, you'd be performing yet ANOTHER file upload, and end up right back in the same spot - processing an upload. `m_u_f($_FILES, '/local/path/to/file')` is what you need.

Comment: @MarcB you should put this in an answer, so OP can accept your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073769/move-uploaded-file-not-working

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

Second argument in function "move_uploaded_file" must be file location on computer, not url.

File location linke "c:/something/something2" not url.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to move your file to a URL which isn't possible since move_uploaded_file works with the local file system, it has no way to do anything with an URL...